# SQL Server duplicate row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with duplicate records. I want to mark whether the record is a duplicate or not in a another column, let's say a column name `Flag`. If the records is a duplicate mark it as 1 in `Flag` column else 0.

How to do this?

I can use a query to select duplicate records.

```
select 
    o.clientid, oc.dupeCount, o.pannodesc, o.CustNo
from 
    CustomerMaster1 o
inner join 
    (SELECT clientid, COUNT(*) AS dupeCount
     FROM CustomerMaster1
     WHERE ISNULL(PanNoDesc, '') <> ''
     GROUP BY clientid
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) oc ON o.clientid = oc.clientid
```

Simply saying, if there are two similar records, mark 1 against the second duplicated row, if three similar records mark 1 against two rows, leaving the original record as 0.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `count(*)` as a window function to calculate the flag:

```
select o.clientid, oc.dupeCount, o.pannodesc, o.CustNo,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by clientId) > 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as IsDuplicate
from CustomerMaster1 o;
```

If you only case about certain records, then you can count them instead:

```
select o.clientid, oc.dupeCount, o.pannodesc, o.CustNo,
       (case when sum(case when PanNoDesc <> '' or PanNoDesc is not null 
                           then 1 else 0
                      end) over (partition by clientId) > 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as IsDuplicate
from CustomerMaster1 o;
```

EDIT:

If you want to modify the data, assuming you have a flag, you can just use these statements as a CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select o.clientid, oc.dupeCount, o.pannodesc, o.CustNo,
             (case when sum(case when PanNoDesc <> '' or PanNoDesc is not null 
                                 then 1 else 0
                            end) over (partition by clientId) > 1
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as NewIsDuplicate
      from CustomerMaster1 o
     )
update toupdate
    set Flag = NewIsDuplicate;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write as

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerMaster1 (clientid INT,PanNoDesc VARCHAR(10),DupFlag bit)
INSERT INTO CustomerMaster1 VALUES(1,'A',NULL ),(1,'B',NULL )


SELECT clientid,PanNoDesc,DupFlag  FROM CustomerMaster1

;WITH CTE AS( 
SELECT  clientid,           
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY clientid ORDER BY clientid ASC) AS rownum
FROM CustomerMaster1
WHERE ISNULL(PanNoDesc, '') <> ''
)
UPDATE T
SET T.DupFlag = (case WHEN rownum > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM CustomerMaster1 T
JOIN CTE ON CTE.clientid = T.clientid

SELECT clientid,PanNoDesc,DupFlag  FROM CustomerMaster1
```

<kbd>[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26d03/1)</kbd>

Edit: Demo based on sample fields provided:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4592f/1

Comment: Simply saying, if there are two similar records, mark 1 against the second duplicated row, if three similar records mark 1 against two rows, leaving the original record as 0.

Comment: Yes, the above will do the same.. as condition is `>1` so first row where rownum=1 will be updated to 0 as required.

Comment: Also .. you want to consider `PanNoDesc` also along with `clientno` for identifying duplicate records?

Comment: yes, but in your one both records will be flagged as 0. Not a single record available as flagged 1. Any idea?

Comment: Added demo.. can you plz post a few entries from the table which is not calculated correctly?

Comment: clientid         pannodesc flag 
5104504  766650996V 0
5104504  766650996V 0